# How to make final String after scanner

Tags: java, string

I wonder how to make my String as final after scanner. I wish that registration was possible only once.

```
public class Register extends Menu {

public static String login, password;
public void register() {
    Console con = System.console();
    System.out.println("Enter login:");
    this.login = con.readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter password:");
    this.password = String.valueOf(con.readPassword());
    menu();
}
```

And there's part with login:

```
public class Logowanie extends Register {

public void logowanie() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String login, haslo;
    boolean isFalse = true;
    while (isFalse = true) {
        System.out.println("Enter login:");
        login = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Enter password:");
        haslo = scanner.next();
        if (login.equals(super.login) && haslo.equals(super.password)) {
            System.out.println("You're in.");
            isFalse = false;
            menu();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can define it inside the while loop at the point of initialization.
final String login=scanner.next();.Any way what i the reason you need it to be final?

Comment: and how can I recall this String in "Logowanie"? If I understand it correctly, once the final set value can't be changed later. This is the reason.

Comment: Got it,to do that you need to save registered users somewhere(database or file).If you don't want the registered user list to persist until next run you can just save them in application memory.

Comment: Yet at every time when user will register once again file will simply changes the value, right?

Comment: You can check login user name and password against the file or database next time so  user wont have to register again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to put a comment.
This line seems to be assigning instead of just checking.

```
while (isFalse = true)
```

should be

```
while (isFalse == true)
```

Comment: It seems that you're right. But I don't know why it works.

Comment: Each time the while statement evaluates the condition, it replaces the value of isFalse with true. Therefore this evaluates to true regardless of the variable value isFalse. Changing the = with == just checks the variable rather than overwriting the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not tested so there could be syntax errors.But using this flow you may achieve what you want to do.
Note:Replace 'regUsers' with a database or a file if you want registration details to prevail till next run.

```
public class User
{
    public User(String uName,String pwd)
    {
        userName=uName;
        password=pwd;
    }
    String userName;
    String password;
    //any other properties as needed
}

public class MyAppMenu extends Menu {
   List<User> regUsers=new ArrayList<User>();

   public void Login()
   {
        //prompt user to enter login details
        //Check if there is a user matching in 'regUsers' list with entered login details 
        //if exists login success continue with rest of the app logic
        //else prompt user to enter details again or register

   }
    public void Register()
   {
        //prompt user to enter registration  details
        //Create new User() object with entered details and add it to 'regUsers' array
        //continue with rest of the app logic or prompt to login

   }
}

public class MainApplicaton 
{ 
   MyAppMenu myMenu=null;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        myMenu=new MyAppMenu();
        myMenu.Login();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you're asking.  However, there are a couple things I can see that might help:

(1) Don't make class fields `public`.  It's considered bad practice to do so, because then any other class could assign some other value to it.  Instead, make the fields `private`, and provide a `getXxx()` method that allows other code to retrieve the field, but don't provide a method to set the field.  That way, your class will have complete control over what happens to the field.

(2) If you want registration to occur only once, you can make your `register()` method check so that it throws an exception if it's called more than once.  One way would be to define a `private boolean` that is initialized to `false`; `register()` can throw an exception if it's `true`, and then set it to `true` the first time it runs successfully.  Or you could do the same thing by checking whether `login` is `null`; your method could throw an exception if `login != null` which would indicate whether someone has logged in already.